# Adding rows that are only associate with previous row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable

I have a table call Municipalities and another call Forms. Forms have 1 Municipality, and stores a variable called municipality_id.

When you select a State from the drop down menu, it will only show Municipalities with that state_id. At that point, I also want to display all the forms associated with the Municipality.

I'm having trouble getting only that Municipality's forms to show, and not all of them.

Here is my code so far:

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">

<div>
<% @municipalities.each do |municipality| %>
  <tr class="active">
    <td><%= link_to municipality.name, municipality_path(municipality) %></td>
    <td><%= municipality.state.state %></td>
    <td><%= municipality.population %></td>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', municipality %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_municipality_path(municipality) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', municipality, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <% end %>
      <% @forms.each do |form| %>
      <tr>
        <%# if @forms.municipality_id == municipality %>
          <% @forms.each do |form| %>
            <td><%= form.form_name %></td>
          <% end %>  
        <%# end %>
      <% end %>
      <tr>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
  def index
  @states = State.all

  if params[:state_id].present?
   @state = params[:state_id]
   @municipalities = Municipality.where(state_id: @state)
   @forms = Form.where(municipality_id: @municipalities)
 else
   @states = State.all
   @municipalities = Municipality.all
 end
```

end

Schema:

```
 create_table "forms", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "form_name"
t.string   "form_link"
t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
t.integer  "municipality_id"
t.integer  "department_id"
end

  add_index "forms", ["department_id"], name:    "index_forms_on_department_id"
  add_index "forms", ["municipality_id"], name: "index_forms_on_municipality_id"

create_table "municipalities", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "form_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "population"
  t.integer  "state_id"
end
```

Any help on how to only display the Forms associated with the Municipality, after they select the State from the drop down. Thanks!

Fixed view, thanks to the response below

```
 <%if @state != nil %>
  <% @state.municipalities.each do |municipality| %>
   <tr class="active">
    <td><%= link_to municipality.name, municipality_path(municipality) %></td>
    <td><%= municipality.state.state %></td>
    <td><%= municipality.population %></td>
   </tr>
    <% municipality.forms.each do |form| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= form.form_name %></td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a municipality to have many forms, and a form to belong to a single municipality. Therefore you shouldn't define form_id in the municipality table. There is not one, but multiple forms associated with the municipality.

In your models define the relations as follows:

**state.rb**

```
has_many :municipalities
```

**municipality.rb**

```
belongs_to :state
has_many :forms
```

**form.rb**

```
belongs_to :municipality
```

Then in your controller load the state with `@state = State.find(params[:state_id]`. you can then iterate over all the municipalities in your form with `@state.municipalities.each do |municipality|` and inside that block you could do `municipality.forms.each do |form|`

Comment: Yes, those associations are all like you suggested. When I try to do state.municipalities.each, or earlier I was trying to do municipality.forms.each, it throws an error saying whatever the 2nd one is, is undefined. So, municipalities is undefined, or forms is undefined.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your quick response. I'll post my new code above.